# Book suggestions for Perturbation Theory in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I've been searching the web for rigorous books on Perturbation Theory, specifically as an undergraduate physics student. In my experience, many quantum mechanics books lack rigor in their explanations. Therefore, I'm seeking mathematically rigorous resources on the subject. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I've already begun reading Kato's book, but it appears to be very detailed and perhaps too advanced for my current needs.